# In a .NET winforms usercontrol, handle a "NameChanged" event

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

An instance of a .NET 4.0 usercontrol exists on a form, with a certain name. Is there a way to get a notification (event?) for when its Name property is being changed (in design mode, within VisualStudio)?

Comment: Yes, you can create a corresponding inherited `System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner` class for that user control. So you can customize the design-time behaviour of (user) controls.

Comment: After searching for a while, i could not find enough info to use it. Can you please provide an example of such a class with a blank winforms usercontrol project (UserControl1)?